# $G$ is torsionfree group and any $x,y \in G$ satisfy $(xy)^n=x^ny^n$, show $G$ is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, contest-math, abelian-groups

> Let $G$ be a torsionfree group and there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for any $x,y \in G$ satisfy $(xy)^n=x^ny^n$. Show that $G$ is abelian.

(The question does not restrict $n$ but as Brian Moehring commented: For the question to make sense we probably need to assume $n>1$)

The question appeared in last year Israel Mathematics Olympiad for undergrads and I'm trying to solve it because I'm taking course on algebraic structures right now. Previously, at the beginning of our course in one of our exercises we had to prove a (somewhat) similar theorem:

> Let $G$ be a group. We say $G$ has the property $\Phi_n$ if for any $x,y \in G$ we have $(xy)^n=x^ny^n$. Show that if $G$ has $\Phi_n,\Phi_{n+1},\Phi_{n+2}$ then $G$ is abelian.

A similar question was asked and answered here previously in [In a group, does $(xy)^n=x^ny^n$ for $n\geq 3$ imply $xy=yx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1437583/702493). I wanted to follow in a similar way, that is- derive some identities. These are the couple I was able to come up with:
$$(xy)^n=x^ny^n\Longrightarrow x^{-1}(xy)^ny^{-1}=x^{n-1}y^{n-1}\Longrightarrow (yx)^{n-1}=x^{n-1}y^{n-1}$$

And notice that

$$(x^ny^n)^n=x^{n^{n}}y^{n^{n}}=x^{n^{2}}y^{n^{2}}$$

So in a similar fashion  we can get

$$x^{n^{2}-1}y^{n^{2}-1}=(xy)^{n^{2}-1}$$

(and I also tried to decompose it back to $n^2-1=(n-1)(n+1)$ and then use the power of $n-1$ but didn't get far)

I figured since we know the group is torsionfree I need to find something to the power of $n$ that equals $e$ so that something must be $e$ but couldn't find the right thing to define. I also thought I'll end up getting something along the lines of $e=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ and that made me think maybe I need to use the commutator somehow. Since we know that the quotient group $G/N$ is abelian if and only if $N$ contains the commutator subgroup of $G$. If I could show the commutator is trivial and $N$ is trivial I'd get and abelian group I think? [**I might be wrong about this! feel free to correct me!**]. Anyhow. I didn't get far with this approach either!

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: @BrianMoehring It's probably my fault for how I stated the problem! I meant 
$$\exists n \in \mathbb{N} , \forall x \in G, \forall y \in G, (xy)^n = x^n y^n$$

I edited the question. Is it clearer now?

Comment: It looks fine now, at least without working on the problem itself.  I deleted my previous comments since they referenced an older version of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$(xy)^n=x^ny^n\Longrightarrow x^{-1}(xy)^ny^{-1}=x^{n-1}y^{n-1}\Longrightarrow (yx)^{n-1}=x^{n-1}y^{n-1}$$
$$x^ny^n=(xy)^n=(xy)(xy)^{n-1}=xyy^{n-1}x^{n-1}= xy^{n}x^{n-1} 
$$
We now know that any $x^{n-1}$ commutes with any $y^n$. Consider  $c=(x^{n-1}y^{-1}x^{1-n})y$. Then $c^n=(x^{n-1}y^{-n}x^{1-n})y^n=y^{-n}y^n=e$ and therefore $c=e$ i.e. $x^{n-1}$ is in $Z(G)$.

Now consider $d=(x^{-1}y^{-1}x)y$ and note that $y^{n-1}$ commutes with $x$. Then$$d^n=x^{-1}y^{-n}xy^n=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy=d.
   $$

Then $d^{n-1}=e$ and so $d=e$ and we are finished.

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems to solve the problem, I’ll leave it unaccepted for a few hours so people would suggest more solutions if there are such and I’ll have more time to try and understand it better. A quick question: How did you conclude $x^{n-1} \in Z(G)$ and did you use that fact afterwards?

Comment: $ c=e$ is equivalent to $x^{n-1}$ commuting with the general $y$.

Comment: It is used afterwards in the final step of simplifying $d^n$ where $y^{n-1}$ is in the centre of $G$.

Comment: Why is $c^n=(x^{n-1}y^{-n}x^{1-n})y^n$?

Comment: If $c=uy$, then $c^n=u^ny^n$. Now let $u=x^{n-1}y^{-1}x^{1-n}$.

Comment: Ah, because $u$ commutes with $y^n$, which in turn is because both $x^{n-1}$ and $y^{-1}$ commute with $y^n$. Thank you.