# Is $(\sigma\circ \tau)^n=\sigma^n\circ\tau^n$?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Is $$(\sigma\circ \tau)^n=\sigma^n\circ\tau^n?$$

a. It seems equivalent to ask whereas composition of permutation is an homomorphism

This seems to be incorrect as $\sigma \circ \tau \neq \tau \circ \sigma$ for $S_n$ such that $n\leq 2$

b. In particular if we have that ${\rm ord}(\sigma)=n$ and ${\rm ord}(\tau)=n$ can we say that $(\sigma\circ \tau)^n=\sigma^n\circ\tau^n={\rm id}^n\circ{\rm id}^n={\rm id}?$

Comment: You mean $n\ge 2$. Anyways this is clearly not true. A sufficient conditionfor this equality to be valid is that $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are disjoint cycles.

Comment: Such a group would be abelian, a contradiction, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437583/in-a-group-does-xyn-xnyn-for-n-geq-3-imply-xy-yx).

Comment: I for one can't figure out what "composition of permutation is a[n] homomorphism" _means_...

Comment: If $\sigma,\tau$ are disjoint, they commute and it will be correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Consider $\sigma=(12), \tau=(23)$. Then $(\sigma\circ\tau)^2=(123)^2=(132)$, whereas $\sigma^2\circ\tau^2={\rm id}$.

Comment: But if they are disjoint then it will hold?

Comment: Yes, @newhere, since disjoint cycles commute with each other.